# Example of exotic $S_5$ as a Galois group

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, symmetric-groups

Is there an example of a sextic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group isomorphic to $S_5$?

The transitive action of the Galois group of this polynomial on the 6 roots of $p(x)$ would give rise to the exotic embedding $S_5\to S_6$.

Comment: Yes, there is ...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: One recipe would go as follows. Let $p(x)$ be a quintic in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ with Galois group $S_5$. Let $L$ be its splitting field. Consider the subgroup $H=\langle (12345),(2354)\rangle$ (=the normalizer of $\langle(12345)\rangle$). Let $K$ be the fixed field of $H$. Then $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=[S_5:H]=6$. There exists a primitive element $a$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}(a)$. Then the minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of $a$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ will work. Basically because the smallest normal subgroup $N$ of $S_5$ containing $H$ is $S_5$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number field data base by Jürgen Klüners:
http://galoisdb.math.upb.de
gives polynomials for many extensions with prescribed Galois group. For example,
$x^6+3x^4-2x^3+6x^2+1$ would be one whose Galois group is $S_5$ on 6 points (transitive group $T_{14}$ in degree 6.)
One can verify this easily using software (e.g. GAP, Pari, Maple, Magma,...)

Answer (score 1):

The Galois groups of sextic polynomials have been determined [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjT8-Pxk7ziAhWys4sKHa_fAi8QFjADegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmjum.math.umn.edu%2Findex.php%2Fmjum%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F002%2F8%2F&usg=AOvVaw2xrmEMwM1UhPhhMkwoblyV). In table $2$ on page $5$, the group T14 is $S_5$, generated by $(15364), (16)(24), (3465)$ in $S_6$.

Comment: Does this reference give a polynomial the realizes that Galois group?

Comment: It explains how to find such a polynomial, I think.

Comment: No, I don't think it gives a construction for such a polynomial, nor does it have such a group as an example. (It describes how -- if one has already a polynomial -- one can costruct other polynomials that factor in certain ways.)

Comment: @ahulpke The article classifies *all* Galois groups of sextic polynomials and shows that $S_5$ must arise. They call it $T14$. I suppose we can find such a polynomial ourself, you are right.